# search for campaigns with multiple values for status parameter

Tags: foursquare

I'd like to ask for the correct parameter to pass when retrieving for campaigns that are both active and notStarted. Thanks!

//not working
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/campaigns/list?status=active&status=notStarted

Answer (score 0):

```
status=pending
```

See: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/campaigns/list

Comment: I'm sorry "pending" does not return "active" nor "notStarted". I am hoping to retrieve campaigns with active and notStarted status in just 1 API call. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by your question then. There only valid values for the status param are "pending,active,expired,all (default=all)". I don't believe you can specify multiple statuses in one request, so you'll need to make two requests or specify "all" and filter out expired campaigns.

Comment: thanks! that is just to verify that it does require 2 requests